# How to import a small text file as a dictionary in python 3

Tags: python-3.x

For a python project I have a text file called clues.txt which looks like this:

```
A#
M*
N%
```

And in python I am trying to read it in as a dictionary so it forms a dictionary looking like this:

```
clues_dict = {'A':'#', 'M':'*', 'N':'%'}
```

The code I'm trying to get to work at the moment is this:

```
    clues_dict = {}

    with open("clues.txt", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            for line in f:
                (key, val) = line.split()
                clues_dict[key] = val

    print(clues_dict)
```

However I get this error:

```
(key, val) = line.split()
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Any help would be gratefully appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str.split()` splits on a character. You don't have that.

```
(key, val) = tuple(line.rstrip())
```

Comment: I would go a little further and make it fully whitespace-agnostic: `key, val = tuple(line.replace(' ', '')`